# How to print a horizontal line on the paper of a thermal printer?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, thermal-printer

In HTML5 we use the `<hr>` tag to draw a horizontal line. Now from `Javascript` I want to post data to a Python project for printing on a **thermal printer** :

```
let data = "Prestation : steak \n";
data += "Quantite : 3 \n";
data += // here I want to draw a horizontal line
data += "Prestation : coca \n";
data += "Quantite : 1";

$.post("localhost:5000/print", JSON.stringify({"printer": "some_printer_name", "payload": data}), function(response) {
    ...
});
```

The Python codes :

file printing.py :

```
import logging
import win32print
import win32ui
import win32con

class Printing(object):
    printer = None
    # Constructor 
    def __init__(self, printer):
        self.printer = printer

    @staticmethod
    def print(printer_name, text):
        try:
            printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
            dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
            dc.CreatePrinterDC(printer_name)
            dc.StartDoc(text)
            dc.StartPage()
            dc.TextOut(10, 10, text)
            dc.EndPage()
            dc.EndDoc()
            win32print.ClosePrinter(printer_handle)
            return True
        except:
            logging.info('Error occured during printing') 
            return False
        finally:
             pass
```

file app.py running in background process waitinf for any call from the Javascript side :

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from printing import Printing

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'If you see this, it means the printer service is up and running !'

@app.route('/print', methods=["POST"])
def print():
    printer_name = request.json['printer']
    data = request.json['payload']
    result = Printing.print(printer_name, data)

    if result:
        response = make_response(
                jsonify(
                    {"message": str("Printing success")}
                ),
                200,
            )
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        return response
    else:
        response = make_response(
                jsonify(
                    {"message": str("Printing failed"), "severity": "error"}
                ),
                500,
            )
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

So how to code the horizontal line ?

Comment: The win32gui module has functions like `MoveToEx` and `DrawTo` for this. You may have to select an appropriate pen or brush into the device context first.

Answer (score 0):

Check below modified JavaScript code to include a string of dash characters (`"-"`) that represents the line. This string is part of the data sent to the Python backend via a POST request. The Python code, using the `win32print` library, receives this data and sends it to the specified printer. Hope it helps

```
let data = "Prestation : steak \n";
data += "Quantite : 3 \n";
data += "--------------------------------\n"; // This will be your horizontal line
data += "Prestation : coca \n";
data += "Quantite : 1";

$.post("http://localhost:5000/print", JSON.stringify({"printer": "some_printer_name", "payload": data}), function(response) {
    // Handle response
});
```

Comment: But how do I know the exact number of dash characters to fill exactly a line of the paper ? Nor less and nor more characters

Comment: @pheromix , In many cases, users will only use one type of printer, right? It would be a good idea to store the number of digits to print as configuration information for each user, or to create a list of several options from which to choose, even if the user uses multiple printers.

Comment: To dynamically calculate or ensure you fill exactly one line, you would need to:
Test and adjust manually by printing test pages and counting how many dashes fit into a line until you find the correct number for your specific setup.
Once you find the exact number, you can replace the line of dashes in your JavaScript code with that number of dash characters.
For example, if you determine that 80 dashes fill one line, you would use: 

data += "----------------------------------------" + // 40 dashes
        "----------------------------------------\n"; // Another 40 dashes to make 80

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com , so there is no ideal way to do it in such a way that it will work on every material of any customer. Because I am developing a project which will be sold to customers who will not have the same material caracteristics